# PhpStorm : add SQL dialect

Tags: phpstorm

We use a class which extends Mysqli at work, and it adds another syntax for prepared statements, something like :

```
<?php
$req = MySQLiWrapperClass::getInstance()->prepare('
    INSERT INTO
        table
    SET
        field = :field_value:s
    ')
    ->bindNamedValue('field_value', 'stackOverflow')
    ->execute();
```

The class will then transform `:field_value:s` to `?` before executing the query.

Problem is, when using MySQL SQL dialect in PhpStorm, this syntax will trigger an error because this syntax is not recognized.

Is there a way to declare a new SQL Dialect, in which I could add this specific syntax ?

Comment: What your doing sounds just like PDO syntax (with an extra colon and type appendage) which PhpStorm recognises. Why not just use PDO instead of MySQLi?

Comment: I know it looks like PDO, but we also have some other syntax changes which are not allowed in PDO either.

Comment: @martin if adding a new custom SQL dialect is not possible yet, yes, that would be the best answer.

Comment: You cannot add your own SQL Dialect just like that (I mean -- code it as a plugin in Java, do the all stuff needed -- will work, why not). The issue in your code is in custom syntax for parameters (`:field_value:s`) -- this can be bypassed by specifying your own syntax in `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | User Parameters` -- this has nothing to do with SQL Dialects as far as I'm concerned (you are not providing new keywords or actual query syntax).

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, I'll check this !

Comment: @LazyOne that doesn't seem to work : I typed `:(\w+):[s|i|d]` with scopes "in script" and "in literals", for all languages, and nothing changed.

Comment: Works fine with `:(\w+\:[d|i|s])` + ordering matters.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to declare a new SQL Dialect, in which I could add this specific syntax?

You cannot add your own SQL Dialect just like that (that's not configurable via some GUI).

What I mean is: Yes, you can, but you have to code it as a plugin in Java, do the all stuff needed -- it will work.

---

The issue that you are having here has *nothing to do with SQL Dialect* -- you are not providing new keywords or actual query syntax (or stuff like that).

The issue in your code is in **custom syntax for parameters** (`:field_value:s` vs `:field_value`).

This can be resolved by specifying your own syntax at `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Database | User Parameters`:

- Pattern: `:(\w+\:[d|i|s])`
- Scope: PHP & MySQL at very least *(based on your code sample)*
- Where: in `literals` at very least

**Important:** order of the rules matters as well.

Here is what I did and how it works:

[image]