# PhpStorm - declare new type of comment in queries

Tags: phpstorm

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412719/phpstorm-add-sql-dialect), we also use another syntax in our SQL queries, which looks like that :

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    first_criteria = true
    //withCondition//AND second_criteria = false
```

The `//withCondition//` syntax allows us to update the query by activating or disabling said line.

If possible, I'd want to be able to tell PhpStorm this specific syntax in SQL queries is a comment, so it won't display an error anymore.

Comment: Such functionality does not exist -- at very least I'm not aware of such stuff. You may file Feature Request ticket at [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) and one day it may get implemented (if devs will see the interest from other users and some adoption in commonly used frameworks/code)

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway !

Comment: At very least -- if it exist or there are ways to make it work right now -- they will tell you

Comment: Thanks, the ticket is created : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35746