# Is there a way or a plugin to configure SQL Dialects as DQL in PhpStorm?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpstorm, dql

In PhpStorm, I can change global, project or directories settings with existing SQL Dialects, but is there a way to configure SQL Dialects as Symfony/DQL in PhpStorm or a way to detect that `App:Panel` is a valid entity, not a table? (*`App:Panel` table name is `te_panel`*)

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412719/phpstorm-add-sql-dialect) which explains that we have to add a Java plugin, because it's currently not possible to add a new SQL Dialect on PhpStorm.

As example, this is an error that PhpStorm is throwing: 
[image]

The `:` between App and Panel is not understood. It cannot understand the table name provided (because I provide the name of the Symfony entity).

Comment: No, it's not possible, as DQL use entity php variable name and not sql column name. Also, this is not proper DQL, at least not how I know it... I wrote a long example of DQL some time ago, take a good look, hoping it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293878/make-an-iterable-array-of-objects-in-php-for-twig/41306677#41306677 (be careful as I wasn't able to use php variable name in my answer, the OP did not copy his entity)

Comment: Thanks @Preciel , but it seems there is an error in your link. 404 error.

Comment: I made a new example of DQL here... you can check.. ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470552/doctrine-condition-on-associative-table-when-joining-many-to-many

Comment: Thanks a lot @Preciel, your solution is interesting. Our team problem is not how to use query builder, but only to detect errors and warning with PhpStorm. We're only doing some internal quality tests and we cannot change source code. Application is very big, there is a lot of DQL code.

Comment: yeah, I can understand... It was only for reference... don't worry... ;)

Answer (score 4):

DQL is not supported.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9948 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

You may try and treat `App:Panel` as placeholder (similar to how it was described in that [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412719/phpstorm-add-sql-dialect)). But I have no ideas if it will help (have not really worked with Symfony/DQL so cannot test it myself).

What I may suggest though -- threat the whole query as plain text. Yes, no syntax highlighting and stuff but will not show errors either.

How? One way by placing special comment just before the string, e.g.

```
->query(/** @lang text */'SELECT ...');
```

Or by disabling Language Injection rule for SQL altogether.

Alternatively try what has been suggested [in this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9948#comment=27-2372391) -- custom SQL detection syntax(?): https://gist.github.com/willemnviljoen/d20ad8ad0cc365a7e80744328246610f

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tried your solution. But App:Panel is not never detect as a parameter, perhaps because table name cannot be considered as a parameter. I will do more tests this evening and come back.

Comment: With your alternate solution, I found a way to detect App:Panel as a parameter, there is no more error detected on it, but now PhpStorm is detecting the `c` alias as an error... I think it isn't possible to avoid these errors.