# doctrine condition on associative table when joining many to many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, dql

I have a *many-to-many* relationship between 2 entities: `Books` <--> `Account`

How can I write theDQL with condition on the associative table?

This is an example, written in SQL:

```
SELECT books.*, account.id FROM books 
LEFT JOIN account_books ON books.id = account_books.books_id AND account_books.account_id = 17 
LEFT JOIN account ON account.id = account_books.account_id
```

Answer (score 1):

In your BooksRepository, should be something like that

```
public function getAccountBooks($accountId) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select("b.paramA", "b.paramB", "b.paramC", "acc.paramA")
                ->from('AppBundle:Books', 'b')
                ->leftJoin('AppBundle:AccountBooks', 'acb', 'WITH', 'b.id=acb.id')
                ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Account', 'acc', 'WITH', 'acc.id=acb.id')
                ->where("accountId = :accountId")
                ->setParameters(array(
                    new Parameter('accountId', $accountId),
                ))
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult();
}
```

Do note that DQL use entity parameters and not SQL columns name

And then in your `action` function:

```
$accountBooks=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Books')
          ->getAccountBooks($accountId);
```

Comment: Well i wanna select all the books and also know which one's does user #17 have, so i can't use where.

Comment: @YuraV Said like that, I don't think that your query example does what you want either... If you want to know which books user#17 have, then remove the `where` and `setParameters` as well as the function parameter. Then gather your data, and filter with PHP once you got the query result

Comment: No worry, i've tested SQL query and it works like a charm, if user owns a book account.id will be 17 otherwise NULL. 
Currently i'm doing $query->leftJoin("books.account_books", "account_books", "WITH", 'account_books.id = :user_id') - but that puts condition on account table, so when i group by books.id there is no garantie i'll get account.id = 17

Comment: an idea just hit me i can $query->select("MAX(account.id)") and it works, thx man! But my question still stands because this way SQL server does a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: It's better, and recommander to have SQL do the work if you can. PHP will take more ressources most of the time to do the same task.