# PhpStorm PDO SQL dialect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpstorm, prepared-statement

I always have the problem in PhpStorm that my PDO prepared statements are underlined as "Method '(ex. execute)' not found in subject class".

Is there any possibility to add PDO/prepared statements to the SQL dialect in PhpStorm, so it won't show a Warning anymore?

[image: Displayed Warning at every PDO function]

Comment: please add the code you currently have issues with

Comment: seems like a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412719/phpstorm-add-sql-dialect

Comment: @janmyszkier it isn't a duplicate bc I do not get errors, but Warnings (which are annoying)

Comment: I've have the problem with any PDO function, like prepare(), execute(), fetch(), ...

Comment: PhpStorm does recognise `execute` as a member of the statement object which is returned by the prepare metdod of the PDO object. At least it does for me.

Comment: **This has NOTHING to do with SQL Dialects.** It's about typehinting of your variables/fields. You need to typehint your `$pdo` properly. Right now IDE does not know that `$this->pdo` is an instance of `\PDO` and therefore does not recognize `prepare()` method. As a result of that the `$stat` is of unknown type (in IDE eyes) which translates to `execute()` as well. Do what **Justinas** have said -- that's the best way -- your `$stat` will now be recognized properly. Otherwise you may do what **janmyszkier** said -- but that should be unnecessary if the above is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think dialect means error checking in `SELECT idPeriod FROM tblPeriod DESC Limit 1` (shouldn't it be `ORDER BY idPeriod DESC`?. What is your `$this->pdo` if it's magic method and PHPStorm does not see it's implementation, then it will issue a warning. Simply apply documentation to this field:

```
class OPClass {
   /**
    * @property PDO $pdo
    */
   public $pdo;
```

Comment: If it isn't a magic property then the correct annotation is `@var` (you can just type `/**` and *enter* and PhpStorm will generate the template for you.

Answer (score 2):

in this case

```
/* @var PDOStatement $stat */
$stat->execute();
```

will allow PHPStorm to understand the Object under the variable

Comment: Not really necessary. Annotating `$this->pdo` at its declaration will automatically fix this and many other code intelligence issues.

Comment: I agree, but that is only possible if you have the chance to modify that class, and it's not vendor provided. Hence my suggestion to annotate the variable inside the code you have access to and ownership over.